# SQL Server : create future dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How do I create future dates in SQL? For example, I want to be able to use my date range and show everything for just next month (purchase orders), then another for two months out, etc. I have used the fn NOW() for the current date/time but this doesn't help me at all for showing records for next month, etc.

Thanks

This is for a SQL query that in doing in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: And how will you be using this? Do you need to outer join against the list of dates or is it just to be used as a search filter?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use MySQL you can use:

```
SELECT date_col FROM your_table
WHERE date_col BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

For MS-SQL (it should work):

```
SELECT date_col FROM your_table
WHERE date_col BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(Month, 1, GETDATE())
```

For Oracle (it should work):

```
SELECT date_col FROM your_table
WHERE date_col BETWEEN SYSDATE AND add_months(SYSDATE, 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function to create dates relative to another date. The following call will generate a date exactly one month in the future:

```
DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE())
```

You can use negative numbers to go *back* as well as forward. There are many other increments you can use, e.g. year, day, week, quarter, millisecond etc.